# How to test React Native Button in Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

How could I test a press in react native? (react-native-elements)
So the code I want to test is:

```
<ListItem
    containerStyle={styles.container} 
    titleContainerStyle={styles.title} 
    chevronColor={'#70be1d'} 
    rightIcon={{name:'check'}}
    key={id} 
    title={name}
    hideChevron={!checked} 
    onPress={ ()=>onMeasureRowPressed(id) }  
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in two different ways, direct or indirect.

direct:

```
 const wrapper = shallow(< ListItem />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    expect(wrapper.state('pressedRow')).toBe('');
    instance.onMeasureRowPressed('1234');
    expect(wrapper.state('pressedRow')).toBe('1234');
```

indirect:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ListItem />);
    expect(wrapper.state('pressedRow')).toBe('');
    wrapper.find('ListItem').simulate('keyPress', {key: 'foo'});
    expect(wrapper.state('pressedRow')).toBe('1234');
```